# Why does dynamically adding an option to a select element alter its selectedIndex?

Tags: javascript, html

Plain and simple: Why does adding the option to the select element alters its selectedIndex and is there a way to either:

1. Prevent this behavior
2. Detect it

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list");
list.selectedIndex = -1;
document.write("</br>Selected index: " + list.selectedIndex);
$(list).append('<option value="foo">foo</option>');
document.write("</br>Selected index: " + list.selectedIndex);
list.selectedIndex = -1;
document.write("</br>Selected index: " + list.selectedIndex);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="list">      
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **selectedIndex**
>
> [By assigning -1 to this property, all items will be deselected. Returns -1 if no items are selected.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/selectedIndex)

For a normal `select`, it's only possible to have no items selected when there are no items to select. As soon as you add at least one item, a selection *must* exist.

If you have a `select multiple`, however, the value will be preserved.

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list");

document.write("</br>Selected index: " + list.selectedIndex);
$(list).append('<option value="foo">foo</option>');
$(list).append('<option value="foo">foo</option>');
$(list).append('<option value="foo">foo</option>');
document.write("</br>Selected index: " + list.selectedIndex);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="list" multiple>      
</select>
```

Comment: What if only one option is there ?

Comment: Is where? `select` or `select multiple`?

Comment: As I said: in a normal `select` dropdown, exactly one option is displayed/selected at all times -- except when there are no options at all.

Comment: @Blazemonger But then again, why is it possible to clear the selection after adding an option by setting the selectedIndex to -1? I've updated the snippet.

Comment: Not sure, to be honest. All I can say is, you probably shouldn't do that anyway, since it's only possible in JS and not through normal user interaction. Use `select multiple`, radio buttons, or `<option value="">Select one</option>` if you need to be able to have no option selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually reset it after adding an option, basically add `list.selectedIndex = -1;` after `$(list).append('<option value="foo">foo</option>');`

Comment: Sure, but I wouldn't have asked the question in the first place if that was an option :)